# RedirectAttributes changes object id between controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate in my project. Also I have 2 controllers `UserController` and `BookController` where `BookController` redirects to the users page and I am passing a `Book` object in addition.

I've found I can do this with `RedirectAttributes` but the problem is that the `id` of the passed `Book` object is changed during this transition to `user.id`.

**BookController.java**

```
public class BookController {

@RequestMapping("/users/{user_id}/books/edit/{book_id}")
  public String editBook(@PathVariable("user_id") int user_id, @PathVariable("book_id") int book_id, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){
    bookDetail = this.bookService.getBookById(book_id)
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("bookDetail", bookDetail);
    System.out.println(bookDetail);
    return "redirect:/users/"+user_id;
  }  

}
```

Prints: *id=8, title=Motylek, description=Some description, user_id=2*.

**UserController.java**

```
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
  public String detailUser(@ModelAttribute("bookDetail") Book bookDetail, @PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    User u = this.userService.getUserById(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", u);
    model.addAttribute("bookDetail", bookDetail);
    System.out.println(bookDetail);
    return "user";
  }
}
```

Prints: *id=2, title=Motylek, description=Some description, user_id=2*.

Do you have and idea why this happens or is it a bug? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the `Book` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your `Book` class has a property called `id`, ie. a getter or setter called `getId()` and `setId(..)`.

When Spring parses the request URL, it stores path segments as declared in the corresponding `@RequestMapping`. So for

```
/your-app/users/2
```

and

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
```

It will store

```
id=2
```

as a request parameter.

Spring will then proceed to generate an argument for

```
@ModelAttribute("bookDetail") Book bookDetail
```

It will check the various request, session, servlet attributes for an entry with the name `bookDetail`. (If it doesn't find one, it will create one and add it to the request attributes.) In your case, it will have found the object in the `HttpSession`. It will then bind any request parameters to matching object properties. Since the parameter above is called `id`, it will be bound to the `Book` property `id`.

You should be good by changing

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{user_id}")
```

along with the corresponding `@PathVariable`.